# .htaccess refuses to redirect URLs without file extensions - straight to 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

So I've been tinkering. Apache's `.htaccess` was redirecting my WWW client just fine (if there is no WWW present, 301 to the same URL with a WWW included), and it was redirecting things with file extensions (i.e. `index.html` will redirect to `index.php`). It's only URLs that are without an extension. It refuses to decipher them.

My current file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Clean URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NS,L,R=permanent]

# Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thevgc\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.thevgc.net/$1 [NS,L,R=permanent]
```

I've been trying to figure this out all night long now. `mod_rewrite` is enabled, and I had to create a symbolic link to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.conf` before actually making the file, which consists of the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Thoughts on this dilemma of mine?

Comment: Is your .htaccess enabled? Try putting some garbage text at the top and see if it generates 500 error in your browser or not.

Comment: I scribbled in `HAHAHAH THIS SHOULD TOTALLY BREAK EVERYTHING` which didn't break anything.

Comment: Well that means your setup doesn't have .htaccess enabled. Please enable .htaccess in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.10. From what I've been made to understand, I don't have one, and instead have `apache2.conf`. Or if I do, I certainly have no idea where to find it.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu at present but look in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory.

Comment: That's a no-go. `ls /etc` returned `hosts.deny`, `hp`, `ifpludg`. There's no `httpd` folder.

Comment: But my Apache error log is showing that HAHAHAHA is an invalid command.

Comment: Scratch that stuff above. Looks like I had a `$_GET` floating around in my URL that was preventing the HAHAHAHA stuff from activating somehow. Removed the WWW URL redirect code and the $b=8 from my URL, returned a 500 error. Removed the HAHAHAHA, is now working. Still 404s when trying to get a non-directory, non-file page.

Comment: The error log has now spit out `[Sat Nov 24 20:38:09 2012] [error] [client 10.0.0.4] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/www/game (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://10.0.0.3/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO! I found the answer to my problem. Looks like if you run the command `a2dismod negotiation` it magically starts working, or at least, it did in my case. Problem solved, case closed, thread done. The mystery has been solved.